# Cannot resolve symbol 'Registration'

Tags: java, android

My imports:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.GoogleClientRequestInitializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
```

Part of the code:

```
private static Registration regService = null;
private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
private Context context;
```

And they cannot resolve the symbol 'Registration'. I dont know and dont find, what I have to compile.

Comment: You have to import Registration if it is in other package.

Comment: try clean project and rebuilding it.

Comment: I have turn auto import on

Comment: just Ctrl + Shift+ O and see what happens. if the error still exists you have to add the lib in your build path.

Comment: @agpt already thy that

Comment: @StefanBeike which lib I have to add?

Comment: Puhhh. I am realy sure Registration is a common name in many other projects. I need more information about the Registration class to give you a hint.

Comment: I want to implements google cloud messaging

Comment: then you need the gcm.jar

Comment: I added in libs folder and write this in my grandle file :    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

Comment: specify full class name

Comment: full class name of ... ?